# I need to transform each element of a matrix if a a condition is met using a comprehension

Tags: python

I have the matrix "array". I need to traverse this matrix, and test each element of it, if element `x!=0` else `x=0`. I've tried to use this but it does not accept the `else`. To simplify, the dimension is fixed at 500x9. I have done this:

```
ds_Entropy = [array[i][j] for i in range(500) for j in range(9) if array[i][j] !=0  else "0" for i in range(500) for j in range(9)]
```

Everything from the `else` onward is wrong. The above description is simplified, what I really need is:

*for a matrix M with elements Mij, if MiJ !=0 then calculate Rij = sum(all column elements of Mij)*LOG(Mij) if Mij !=0 else Mij = 0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, for each element you are trying to print the value if different than zero and "0" if equals zero. You can do that inline like this:

```
import numpy as np
r_size = 500
c_size = 9
array = np.random.randint(10, size = (r_size, c_size))     
ds_Entropy = [array[i][j] if array[i][j] != 0  else "0" for i in range(r_size) for j in range(c_size)]
```